# For which numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ will the function $f(x)=\frac{(ax+b)}{(cx+d)}$ satisfy $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In the composition function when we put $f(x)$ into it and solve it, we got a quadratic equation.  Now please tell me how to solve that quadratic equation to reach upto correct answer.

Comment: Do you know how composition of such Möbius functions is related to matrix multiplication?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen no I don't. Please tell me if there is any.

Comment: @Servaes I think Case is complex about the solution of quadratic equation , not of solving composition function.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by *for which numbers...*? We cannot determine four quantities from only one equation.

Comment: @Allawonder Sorry for inconvenience but this question is given in calculus text book.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you understand the composition part. Hence, you should know that the condition reduces to $$Cx^2+(D-A)x-B=0,$$ where $C=ac+cd,D-A=bc+d^2-a^2-cd$ and $B=ab+d^2.$ This quadratic vanishes identically when the coefficients vanish. Thus, you must solve the system $$C=0, D=A, B=0,$$ which contains the four unknowns $a,b,c,d.$ Thus there are infinitely many solutions as defined by that system.

Comment: Yes this is working . Thanks.

Comment: But why this question is downvoted?  I am new to this site. Is there any written mistake.

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN I don't know about the down votes. Perhaps they came because you did not show any evidence of what you'd done.

Comment: Ohh this could be